# Delete from database (Athlete)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to delete anyone who has the letter "o" as the second letter in their name, example: "Pool" (that has 'o' at the second place). So I'm searching judging by the persons name. My database consists of athletes' names

It's a task I have, I do apologize for the weird question.

my database is called `athlete`,
I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM `athlete` WHERE name LIKE '_o%'
```

I expect it to show "zero changes" because there are no one in my database who has the letter 'o' as the second letter in their name.

My error message. [image]

Comment: So what is the issue ? What did you get when you run this query ?

Comment: eroor message, ill update now with screenshot

Comment: You have setup foreign key constraint using this table as parent table , with `on delete restrict`.. this is generally done for good measure to avoid accidental deletion and ensure data integrity. Now if you really want to delete this particular data then change the constraints to `on delete cascade` in all the child tables

Comment: "DELETE CASCADE FROM `athlete` WHERE name LIKE '_o%' " like this?

Comment: No. Please read up on foreign key constraint. You will need to redefine the constraints

Comment: *RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table* - Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html  So basically due to `on delete restrict` configured in the `training_session` table, you cannot call any delete operation on the table (it gets rejected even before the query looks for actual rows to delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a foreign key constraint issue. You can not delete the row(s) because there are row(s) on other tables dependent on the `athlete` table.

Comment: but Im not trying to delete anything, because none of the names has the '_o%'

Comment: The DB doesn't know that yet, it has to let you know about the constraint you want to break first. @Lillie